# Does Linq to XML queries call the entire document or just what you query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

For political reasons (arg) my companies public facing website does not have sql persistence available to it. For this reason I am building an sql powered site that also spits out XML for my public site, this site sits on a different server and does not have access to the server the public site is on. I know, it's just as ugly as it sounds, but I think this is my best option for us at the moment.

Anyhow, I have an xml file for our Locations. Marketing (again arg) of course want's an image associated with each location. This means I have a few options, either one, I can manually enter the name of the image as a string and manually put the image in a folder for the public site to access. Or I can have it stored as byte[] data in the db and xml doc. I am exploring that later.

```
<Location>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Name of Loc</Name>
    <Address1>Address Line 1</Address1>
    <City>Loc City</City>
    <State>Loc State</State>
    <Zip>Loc Zip</Zip>
    <Latitude>43.244952</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-82.74054</Longitude>
    <ImageData>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD... (truncated for sanity sake)</ImageData>
    <ImageMimeType>image/jpeg</ImageMimeType>
</Location>
    <Location>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Name of Loc</Name>
    <Address1>Address Line 1</Address1>
    <City>Loc City</City>
    <State>Loc State</State>
    <Zip>Loc Zip</Zip>
    <Latitude>43.244952</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-82.74054</Longitude>
</Location>
<Location>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Name>Name of Loc</Name>
    <Address1>Address Line 1</Address1>
    <City>Loc City</City>
    <State>Loc State</State>
    <Zip>Loc Zip</Zip>
    <Latitude>43.244952</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-82.74054</Longitude>
</Location>
```

So, once I have an XML doc with 90 locations in it and an image for each the xml doc itself will be insanely large.

My question, before I continue down this path is when I make a call to the XML via Linq to XML, am I only calling the info that is being queried or am I pulling the entire XML doc and extracting the info I need?

If I am indeed pulling in the full XML doc, do you have any suggestions on a better approach? Or would the server be able to handle this info fairly quickly?

Comment: I would suggest saving and outputting json. You can serialize that into an object and, work with it how you need and then use it to generate xml if needed in the end. That will greatly reduce the size of the document you are working with as well as make your life easier when working with it.

Comment: From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx): *LINQ to XML provides an in-memory XML programming interface that leverages the .NET Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) Framework.*

Comment: @StephenBrickner That changes absolutely nothing.  You can turn the XML document into an object and work with it too, nor will it reduce the size of the document you are working with.

Comment: To answer your question (which would have taken you 10 minutes to test yourself) is that the entire document is loaded and then processed.

Comment: @Robert McKee that is true you can turn the xml document (much larger) into an object and work with it just the same but again, to store less data you could just store it as json and output it to xml as needed.

Comment: @StephenBrickner The document will not be much larger in XML than it would be in JSON, especially considering that he's storing base64 encoded images in it.

Comment: How is <myNode>some data</myNode> not large than {myNode: some data}. Thats 26 characters compared to 17 and so on as the data gets larger. Especially when it comes to arrays.

Comment: @StephenBrickner I used the above example, replaced the image node with an image I had on hand, and it was 165022 bytes in XML, and 165010 bytes when I converted it to JSON for a .007% savings.  I don't call .007% larger "much larger".

Comment: That's a single node with a single image. Now multiply it by several nodes. Larger is still larger, especially when you consider serialization.

Comment: That was 3 nodes. Extrapolating that out to 300 nodes would be 16502200 bytes in XML and 16501000 bytes in JSON, for a 0.007% savings.

Comment: Don't store the image `for sanity's sake` at the very maximum store the location. If they can all be in one folder not even that and name the images by the location's `ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire document is loaded and then processed.  If you are base64 encoding your images (it appears you are), and sticking them in the XML document, then it will likely get very memory intensive very quickly.

Comment: Thank you Robert, that answers my question. Yes the images are being base64 encoded, I'm going to load up the xml doc with a bunch of images and test what kind of load it has on processing to see if xml is the right route for me. I don't believe JSON will be the answer though, as when it comes down to having the base64 images the JSON will not provide enough advantage to make it worth while.

Comment: @EHaltom  Converting to JSON would be a micro-optimization that wouldn't make or break the concept.  You could also shrink your property names to single characters too, which is another micro-optimization that would save you even more space than going to JSON, but again, isn't worth the bother and makes maintenance more difficult.